# Evaluate ; $\cos 90^\circ \times \tan 90^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry

Evaluate ; $\cos 90^\circ \times \tan 90^\circ$

$$\cos 90^\circ \times \tan 90^\circ$$
$$ 0 \times \infty$$
$$0$$.

Or,

$$\cos 90 \times \dfrac {\sin 90}{\cos 90}$$
$$\sin 90$$
$$1$$

Or,

$$0 \times \dfrac {1}{0}$$
$$\dfrac {0}{0}$$
$$\infty$$

Which one is correct? Or, are there other alternatives?

Comment: It's futile to talk about $\tan 90^\circ$ though you can evaluate $\lim_{x\to \pi/2}\tan x\cos x$(which is $1$).

Comment: tan 90 isn't even really a thing at all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\infty$ is not a number, so you cannot use it in operations. Also, $\tan(90°)$ is not equal to $\infty$, but simply does not exist. So you cannot multiply it by anything.

This means that $\cos(90°)\times\tan(90°)$ in *undefined*, that is does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

For cancellation you have to ensure that you cannot divide by zero.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot cancel it like this actually, cancelling is possible only due to the multiplicative inverse that is for example $2.\frac{1}{2} = 1$ because $\frac{1}{2}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $2$ , also $0$ has no multiplicative inverse here , now in your second argument you cannot cancel $\cos(90)$ term because $\cos(90) = 0$ has no multiplicative inverse here.